# Get Employees before and after specific date of joining from List of Employees with Java stream

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have `List` of `Employee`s with different joining dates. I want to Get Employees before and after specific date of joining from List using streams.

i tried following code,

```
 List<Employee> employeeListAfter = employeeList.stream()
                .filter(e -> e.joiningDate.isAfter(specificDate))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

List<Employee> employeeListBefore = employeeList.stream()
        .filter(e -> e.joiningDate.isBefore(specificDate))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

class Employee{
    int id;
    String name;
    LocalDate joiningDate;
}
```

Is there any way to do this in single stream?

Comment: You can use `partitioningBy`

Comment: Before and after - so you want all employees except those who joined on the date?

Comment: Assuming it's "been an employee at least since", you'll want to split into before and not before, not caring about after at all.

Answer (score 13):

You can use `partitioningBy` as below,

```
Map<Boolean, List<Employee>> listMap = employeeList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(e -> e.joiningDate.isAfter(specificDate)));

List<Employee> employeeListAfter = listMap.get(true);
List<Employee> employeeListBefore = listMap.get(false);
```

[partitioningBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#partitioningBy-java.util.function.Predicate-) Returns a Collector which partitions the input elements according to a Predicate, and organizes them  into a `Map<Boolean, List<T>>`

Note that this won't handle employees with `specificDate`.

Comment: This does not do exactly, what the code in question does - employees with `specificDate` will land in `false` partition, wheres in the code in question in none

Comment: How does adding `specificDate.plusDays(1)` resolve the issue? `specificDate` will still be in the `false` part.

Comment: @Code_Mode you should rather filter the resulting list

Comment: @Andronicus: Only OP knows if this behavior is a bug or a feature. To me, it seems safer to not leave any employee out.

Answer (score 8):

If your list can have entries *that joined on the `specificDate`*, then you may find `groupingBy` useful:

```
Map<Integer, List<Employee>> result = employeeList.stream()
    .map(emp -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(specificDate.compareTo(emp.getJoiningDate()), emp))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(entry -> entry.getKey() > 0 ? 1 : (entry.getKey() < 0 ? -1 : 0),
            Collectors.mapping(entry -> entry.getValue(), Collectors.toList())));

employeeListAfter = result.get(-1);
employeeListBefore = result.get(1);
employeeListOnSpecificDate = result.get(0);
```

The `result` map contains `Employee` records grouped by position relatively to `specificDate`, so you can pick who joined before, after, or on the specified date.

Comment: -1. You are making the false assumption that `compareTo` will only return -1, 0, or 1. In fact LocalDate.compareTo can return any int.

Comment: @MikeFHay Yup, the code [here](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/time/LocalDate.java) would return the difference in years if they're not equal.

Comment: @MikeFHay Thanks for pointing that out. I made a very quick test and jumped to conclusions. Changed implementation (and suddenly it looks complex).

Comment: @ernest_k: You could use the original `compareTo` and call `Integer.signum` on it.

Comment: @JollyJoker Just in case you didn't know, you can link to a specific line in github : like [this](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/time/LocalDate.java#L1859). Clicking on the line number changes the URL directly. Feel free to ignore if you already knew or don't care. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You need to filter out employees with this particular date. Then you can use partitioning:

```
Map<Boolean, List<Employee>> partitioned = employeeList.stream()
    .filter(e -> !e.joiningDate.equals(specificDate))
    .collect(partitioningBy(e -> e.joiningDate.isAfter(specificDate)));

List<Employee> employeeListAfter = partitioned.get(true);
List<Employee> employeeListBefore = partitioned.get(false);
```

This will create a map of collections based on if they fulfill the predicate.

Comment: Learned `partitioningBy`  today.

Comment: No, you can not filter with date as it would filter employees with only specificDate

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Collectors.groupingBy` and use `compareTo` method for grouping employees list based on previous,current and future date

```
Map<Integer, List<Employee>> result = employeeList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e-> e.joiningDate.compareTo(specificDate)< 0 ? -1 : (e.joiningDate.compareTo(specificDate) == 0 ? 0 : 1)));
```

So the output will be

```
key--> -1 ---> will have employees with previous date
key--> 0 ---> will have employees with current date
key--> 1 ---> will have employees with future date
```